# How can I make a gate with two cubes that close/open nonstop?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] gateParts;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gateParts.Length; i++)
        {
            gateParts[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(gateParts[i].transform.position, gateParts[i + 1].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make both cubes to move each other when they collide or touch each other by distance then move them far from each other. close/open the gate nonstop.

[image: Gate]

Comment: How many pieces of your gate are there? Just the two? In that case your `for` should actually throw an error, right?

Comment: It seems like you already programmed something. Can you tell us what's wrong with the code you wrote? Does it cause error messages? Doesn't it do anything? Does it do something, but it's not what you expect it to do?

Comment: And do you insist on doing this in C# or would you be open to alternative approaches? (like a [timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.5/manual/index.html), for example)